# How to set up a testing mongo database for a flask application

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, chai

I have a working flask application, which looks in the following way:

I have my myFolder/app.py with:

```
app = flask.Flask('name')

# and then a lot of routes
@app.route('/api/something', methods=['GET'])
def someName():
   return flask.jsonify(somefile.somefunc())
```

the file with functions looks like:

```
# initialize database connection
client = pymongo.MongoClient(host=os.environ['MONGO_IP'])
db = client[os.environ['MONGO_DB']]

# and then a lot of functions that uses this global db to CRUD something
def somefunc():
   # do something with db
   return
```

it works fine and everyone is happy. But I want to write some tests with chai

---

I want to set up a testing database, populate it with data, make one of the API calls, assert that the data looks ok.

And I do this in the following way:

```
import chai
from myFolder import app

class App(chai.Chai):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # this method is called before all testcases
        os.environ['MONGO_DB'] = 'test_db' # changing the db to test one

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # this method is called after all testcases
        os.environ['MONGO_DB'] = 'normal' # change db to normal

    def test_firstTestCase(self):
        client = app.app.test_client()
        print client.get('/api/something').data  # here is the Problem
```

What surprises me is that the last `print` actually outputs the results from the real database (I expected it to output nothing, because I changed the database name to testing and have not populated it). So how should I properly set up a testing database?

Comment: Are your sure that the *initialize database connection* code gets executed **after** mocking the environment variables?

Comment: based on the output I see, it is not.

Comment: then where do you have `import`s for that file with functions?